# VSTest disk drive error whenever a test asserts

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I have a native unit testing project in Visual Studio 2013 that has been testing the development of a C++ library for many months. Out of seemingly nowhere, Visual Studio has started popping the following message box whenever a test asserts:

```
vstest.executionengine.x86.exe - No Disk:
There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive F:.
```

There are a few tests that access the filesystem, but I commented them out. I tried remaking the entire test project from scratch but it still is happening. Even a simple assert like this will cause the message box to appear:

```
Assert::IsTrue(false);
```

What is causing this behavior?

Comment: I'd try running VS setup in repair mode - maybe some of the vstest executables have disappeared and vs tries to find them on installer disk F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try running VS setup in repair mode - maybe some of the vstest executables have disappeared and vs tries to find them on installer disk F

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not an installation repair issue in my case. It just started to happen after I attached a new USB disk drive while tests were running.

Restarting the machine solved the problem.